# Calling on recursive code with exponential complexity from a loop

Tags: python, recursion, big-o

This code is presented as an example of exponential complexity in an [MIT programming course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-computer-science-mitx-6-00-1x-9):

```
def genSubsets(L):

    if len(L) == 0:
        return [[]] #list of empty set
    smaller = genSubsets(L[:-1]) #all subsets without last element
    extra = L[-1:] #create a list of just the last element
    new = []
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra) #for all smaller solutions, add one with last element
    return smaller+new #combine those with last element and those without
```

If I call on genSubsets with a regular list, I get an answer as expected (a set of all the possible subsets).

```
print(genSubsets([0,1,2]))
#prints - [[], [0], [1], [0, 1], [2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

However, if I try to call it from within a loop (either using list comprehension or by constructing the lists using a sub-loop), and then calling on genSubsets, the function fails to return the expected answer.

```
for i in range(4):
    L = []
    for j in range(i):
        L.append(j)
    #print(L) # works as expected
    print(genSubsets([L])) # produces lists of length two regardless of number input list length
```

I want to call on the function from within the loop because I'm curious to see how the size (i.e. length) of the returned list of subsets grows as the input size grows and to experience how the processing time increases as input list size increases.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to call on genSubsets with progressively larger lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you give it a list with just a single element, so of course you only get two subsets. Change `genSubsets([L])` to `genSubsets(L)`.